# Best way to work with Real Time Data from local file

Tags: javascript, python, real-time

I need to work with realtime data coming from a local file on the user computer. Analize it and display it in real time, using maps & graphs.

My target is to create an electron desktop app or something similar, so on the frontend I would use JS.
To analize the data I want to use Python so, would be the simple Python backend and JS frontend.

What is the best way to start this project? This are the options I have in my mind:

- Flask
- Simply using Python files and call them using child_process from JS
- Sockets

Is there any better idea?

Comment: using POST and GET request, but like that you would have 2 servers running on your pc ,the electron one, and the python one

Comment: Maybe a file watcher so that python detects local file changes and a websocket connection from python to your Frontend.